# Adding new fields into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary

```
    food_dict = [ {
        'food_name': item_name,
        'serving_size': size_serv,
        'serving_calorie': calorie_serv,
        'serving_protien': protein_serv,
        'serving_fat': fat_serv,
        'serving_carb': carb_serv
     } ]
```

I want to be able to add another field into my dictionary.

So for example I want to create a database of foods

```
     food_dict = [ {
        'food_name': fish,
        'serving_size': 40,
        'serving_calorie': 30,
        'serving_protien': 20,
        'serving_fat': 4,
        'serving_carb': 4
     },
     {
        'food_name': chicken,
        'serving_size': 32,
        'serving_calorie': 20,
        'serving_protien': 15,
        'serving_fat': 4,
        'serving_carb': 1
     }
     ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't just have a dictionary. You have a **list** with one dictionary in it.

Use `list.append()` to add a second dictionary:

```
food_dict.append({
    'food_name': 'chicken',
    'serving_size': 32,
    'serving_calorie': 20,
    'serving_protien': 15,
    'serving_fat': 4,
    'serving_carb': 1
 }
```

Comment: Martijn is right - you might want to grab a tutorial on [python](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). A "field" in a dictionary is kind of ambiguous -but I assume you want a additional entry in your list as Martijn showed above.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a list of dictionaries, to which you can add more dictionaries with `food_dicts.append()`.